# IIS 6 problems - IIS seems like blocking the second request

Tags: iis-6, asp.net, html

I'm having very weird issue with IIS. My server is 2003 advanced server. I installed .NET 2 and .NET 4 on that server (.NET 1 is already there). We are running ASP.NET 2.0 site, ASP.NET 4.0 site and ASP.NET MVC site with different pool.. ASP.NET 2.0 site and ASP.NET MVC 3 (Surprise?) are working fine. I'm having problem with asp.net 4.0 or html.

I created a virtual directory under web site. The execute permission is "Scripts and Execute" and ASP.NET 4.0.30319.

I put a HTML file called a.html under that virtual directory and I click on "Browse" to view the html. It's working fine. I closed the browser and I click on "browse" again for second time. And then, here I got an error.

In IE, I got this error "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage"

In Chrome, I got this below.

This web page is not available
The web page at http://192.168.105.2:170/simpleweb/c.html might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
Error 330 (net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED): Unknown error.

In Firefox, I got this..

Content Encoding Error
        The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression.
        Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.

I'm spending the whole day to figure out but it's not working ... Does anyone has any idea about this issue?

When I tried with asp.net 4 site, I got the same issue as well. but asp.net 2 and asp.net mvc are working fine..

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

Here is the log

```
Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 6.0
Version: 1.0
Date: 2011-12-14 06:27:57
Fields: date time s-sitename s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status sc-bytes cs-bytes 
2011-12-14 06:27:56 W3SVC1531730165 127.0.0.1 GET /simpleweb/c.html - 170 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+5.2;+.NET+CLR+1.1.4322;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E) - 200 0 0 378 284
2011-12-14 06:28:23 W3SVC1531730165 127.0.0.1 GET /simpleweb/d.html - 170 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+5.2;+.NET+CLR+1.1.4322;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E) - 200 0 0 343 284
2011-12-14 06:28:26 W3SVC1531730165 127.0.0.1 GET /simpleweb/d.html - 170 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+5.2;+.NET+CLR+1.1.4322;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E) - 200 0 0 378 373
2011-12-14 06:28:26 W3SVC1531730165 127.0.0.1 GET /simpleweb/d.html - 170 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+5.2;+.NET+CLR+1.1.4322;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E) - 200 0 0 378 489
2011-12-14 06:28:28 W3SVC1531730165 127.0.0.1 GET /simpleweb/d.html - 170 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+5.2;+.NET+CLR+1.1.4322;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E) - 200 0 0 378 489
2011-12-14 06:28:29 W3SVC1531730165 127.0.0.1 GET /simpleweb/d.html - 170 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+5.2;+.NET+CLR+1.1.4322;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E) - 200 0 0 378 489
2011-12-14 06:28:29 W3SVC1531730165 127.0.0.1 GET /simpleweb/d.html - 170 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+5.2;+.NET+CLR+1.1.4322;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E) - 200 0 0 378 489
2011-12-14 06:28:33 W3SVC1531730165 127.0.0.1 GET /simpleweb/d.html - 170 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+5.2;+.NET+CLR+1.1.4322;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E) - 200 0 0 378 489
2011-12-14 06:29:27 W3SVC1531730165 127.0.0.1 GET /simpleweb/d.html - 170 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+5.2;+.NET+CLR+1.1.4322;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E) - 200 0 0 378 284
```

Comment: Is it an actual html page, an asp with a .html extension, or an html page that is being passed to asp.dll (or other script engine)?

Comment: It's an actual html page. no script.. just html tag, body tag, p tag and one string inside..

Comment: Can you try and capture the request/response stream using something like Fiddler or Live HTTP Headers (on Firefox) - it looks like the webserver is mangling the headers somehow that's confusing the browser.

Comment: Ya. Thanks! I managed to fix it by disabling HTTP compression at service tab .. I think it's not the best way but it works

Comment: I have the same error, does anyone know a better solution then turning of compression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix it by disabling HTTP compression at the service tab on Websites (not individual)'s properties windows.